# Angular 4 / AngularFire 2 Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: angular, firebase-notifications

I try to use AngularFire2 to implement FCM and got stuck with using it.

```
initCloudMessages(): void {

    let messaging = this.firebaseApp.messaging;

    messaging().requestPermission().then( function(){

        console.log( 'request enabled' );

    }).catch(function(){

        console.log( 'request permission error' );

    });

}
```

It gives me an error - messaging is not a funciton.

Are there any examples of usgin AngularFire2 for FCM?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, Did you include BOTH:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
```

In the top of your file?
Give it a shot!

Comment: Can you please share complete example? Or at least the required steps?